# RX throttle on WinRT TemplatedControl

Tags: windows-runtime, system.reactive, winrt-xaml, winrt-async

I have some problems with thread synchronization in my Templated control (trying to do a AutoComplete control)

Inside my control I have this code:

```
protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        var searchTextBox = GetTemplateChild("SearchTextBox") as TextBox;
        if (searchTextBox != null)
        {
            var searchDelegate = SearchAsync;

            Observable.FromEventPattern(searchTextBox, "TextChanged")
                .Select(keyup => searchTextBox.Text)
                .Where(TextIsLongEnough)
                .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
                .Do(ShowProgressBar)
                .SelectMany(searchDelegate)
                .ObserveOn(Dispatcher)
                .Subscribe(async results => await RunOnDispatcher(() =>
                                                                      {
                                                                          IsInProgress = false;
                                                                          SearchResults.Clear();
                                                                          foreach (var result in results)
                                                                          {
                                                                              SearchResults.Add(result);
                                                                          }
                                                                      }));
        }
    }
```

And it is complaining that inside my ShowProgressBar method I'm trying to access code that was marshalled by another thread.

If I comment out the Throttle and the ObserveOn(Dispatcher) it works just fine, but it does not throttle my service calls as I want to.

If I only comment out the Throttle part, Nothing happens at all.

Comment: This is not an answer, but a quick comment - I don't think you need the `async`/`await` in your code. Rx effectively does the awaiting for you. Try it without and let me know if it still works fine.

Comment: True Enigmativity - the code works without async/await as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asti's got the right idea, but a far better approach would be to provide the `IScheduler` argument to Throttle instead:

```
// NB: Too lazy to look up real name 
.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500), CoreDispatcherScheduler.Instance)
```

This will make operations below it happen on the UI thread (including your ShowProgressBar), up until the SelectMany.

Comment: This did solve the problem! The syntax I used was .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500), CoreDispatcherScheduler.Default)

Answer (score 1):

Every dependency object requires that any changes to dependency properties [be made only on the Dispatcher thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.dispatcher%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). The `Throttle` is using a different scheduler, hence making any changes to the UI in a subsequent `Do` combinator would result in an access exception.

You can resolve this by:

1. Add an [ObserveOnDispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211843%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) before any actions which cause side-effects on the Dispatcher. Optionally use another scheduler down the pipeline.
2. Use [Dispatcher.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh199416.aspx) to execute side-effects through the dispatcher. E.g.,  `.Do(() => Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(ShowProgressBar)))`

Comment: Hi, well if I add ObserveOnDispatcher() before the call to Do(ShowProgressBar) the ShowProgressBar never gets invoked. In Win8 the dispatcher is a CoreDispatcher and uses .RunAsync() which I do use in the code above. My problem is that the code never get invoked if I use the ObserveOnDispatcher() before that call.